# Allow user input on Vue input prefilled with server data

Tags: vue.js

I have a few text inputs that receive data from a backend API. I also need to allow user to enter his data to the inputs. How do I fix the code below to allow for it?

```
<input
  type='text'
  class='form-control input--square'
  id='cell'
  placeholder='Женат'
  :value='profile.persAdditionalInfo.family === 1 ? "Married" : "Not married"'
  @input='profile.persAdditionalInfo.family = $event.target.value'
/>
```

`profile.persAdditionalInfo.family` receives either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [v-model](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

```
data: () => ({
    message: null
})

<input v-model="message" placeholder="отредактируй меня">
```